# How to Update Documentation of ROSJava PubSub Example?

Tags: rosjava

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The example ROSJava publish/subscribe programs given [here](http://docs.rosjava.googlecode.com/hg/rosjava_core/html/getting_started.html#publishers-and-subscribers) are outdated.  Specifically the constructor for org.ros.namespace.GraphName is private and replaced with factory method GraphName.of(...).

How does one go about updating the docs?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/39443/how-to-update-documentation-of-rosjava-pubsub-example?/) by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) on ROS Answers with karma: 328 on 2012-07-21

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If it is just one thing, just create a ticket.

```
https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/list
```

If it is many things, checkout the rosjava source, change the docs, create a ticket and submit the patch.
See

```
https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/checkout
```

and

```
https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/source/checkout
```

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2012-07-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [liangfok](https://answers.ros.org/users/1811/liangfok/) on 2012-07-21**:
Thanks.  I have created the ticket:  https://code.google.com/p/rosjava/issues/detail?id=133

**Comment by [cyberguy42](https://answers.ros.org/users/5314/cyberguy42/) on 2013-08-30**:
I'm glad I found this post, because the example still hasn't been changed.
For others in this situation, that example would be 'return GraphName.of("rosjava_tutorial_pubsub/talker");'